# using Mysql Query Profiler to know the execution time of the queries and the performance in php script

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, profiler

I would like to use mysql query profiler in the php script. So that after i execute any queries it need to display the execution time of the query.

Suggest the best way to use this also share any other scripts like query profiler.

Comment: you mean the built-in set profiling=1/show profiles profiler? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

Comment: Yes VolkerK. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Before:

You need to set the `profiling` to `1` before you execute your query in order to get access to the profiling information.

```
mysql_query("SET profiling = 1");
```

### After:

After you've executed the query you want to test you need to execute the following query.

```
$a = mysql_query("
     SELECT query_id, SUM(duration) AS duration 
     FROM information_schema.profiling
     GROUP BY query_id ORDER BY query_id DESC LIMIT 1
     ");

//in case you want to loop through more than one profile
while($b = mysql_fetch($a))
{
    echo 'ID: '.$b['query_id'].'<br>Duration: '.$b['duration'].' seconds';
}
```

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/profiling-table.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply rubayeet. But im not able to create a two db connections. ANy solution ?

Comment: What would you use the second db connection for? $mysqliObj in rubayeet example would be the same db object you use throughout your scripts

Comment: Now i have fixed it. I created another user and connected to the information_schema database. Now the database is connected. But the results were empty no records got inserted in the profiling table. How to make sure profiling is set ?

Comment: VolkerK , I created another db object to use for setting the profiling and to get results from profiling table.

Comment: I am able to see the profiling results in mysql client but im not able to get the results from the php script.Is it set profiling needs any permission to execute from php script ?

Comment: When you create the mysqli object, don't supply the dbname parameter, instead switch between your db and information_schema using mysqli::select_db() method.